# Incrementing os.clock() in Lua

Tags: unit-testing, lua, sleep

**Summary:** Can I cause time to (appear to) pass in my script without busywaiting? Using `os.execute('sleep 1')` doesn't cut it (and also wastes time).

**Details**
I have [a library](http://github.com/Phrogz/LXSC) that does work after specific intervals. I currently schedule this by injecting a table into a time-sorted list. Roughly:

```lua
local delayedWork = {}
function handleLater( data, delaySeconds )
  local delayedItem = { data=data, execTime=os.clock() + delaySeconds }
  local i=1
  for _,existing in ipairs(delayedWork) do
    if existing.execTime > delayedItem.execTime then break else i=i+1 end
  end
  table.insert(delayedWork,i,delayedItem)
end
```

Later on I periodically check for work to do. Roughly:

```lua
function processDelayedWork()
  local i,last = 1,#delayedWork
  while i<=last do
    local delayedItem = delayedWork[i]
    if delayedItem.execTime <= os.clock() then
      table.remove(delayedWork,i)
      -- use delayedItem.data
      last = last-1
    else
      i=i+1
    end
  end
end
```

*(The fact that this uses CPU time instead of wall time is an issue for a different question. The fact that I repeatedly shift the array during processing instead of one compacting pass is an optimization not relevant here.)*

When I am running unit tests of the system I need to cause time to pass, preferably faster than normal. However, calling `os.execute('sleep 1')` consumes one wall clock second, but does not cause `os.clock()` to increment.

```
$ lua -e "require 'os' print(os.clock()) os.execute('sleep 1') print(os.clock())"
0.002493
0.002799
```

I can't use `os.time()` because this is only integer seconds (and less than that on systems compiled to use `float` instead `double` for numbers):

```
$ lua -e "require 'os' print(os.time()) os.execute('sleep 0.4') print(os.time())"
1397704209
1397704209
```

**Can I force time to pass in my script without just busywaiting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write your own clock function that does what you want?

```
do
   local clock = os.clock
   local increment = 0
   os.clock = function(inc)
     increment = increment + (inc or 0)
     return clock()+increment
   end
end
print(os.clock())
os.clock(1)
print(os.clock())
```

This will print `0.001 1.001` or something similar.

Comment: Seems a little odd to modify the runtime just to make the unit testing a little easier. It's too bad that there isn't a better solution, but you get the acceptance for this good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Paul answered this already: make `os.clock` return whatever you need.

I'm adding an implementation that lets you control how fast time passes according to `os.clock` \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\.

```
do
    local realclock = os.clock
    local lasttime = realclock()
    local faketime = lasttime
    local clockMultiplier = 1
    function setClockMultiplier(multiplier)
        clockMultiplier = multiplier
    end
    function adjustTime(offsetAmount)
        faketime = faketime + offsetAmount
    end
    function os.clock()
        local now = realclock()
        adjustTime((now - lasttime) * clockMultiplier)
        lasttime = now
        return faketime
    end
end
```

You can now call `setClockMultiplier` to freely slow down or speed up the passage of time as reported by `os.clock`. You can call `adjustTime` to advance or retard the clock by arbitrary amounts.

Comment: _"Isn't the entire point to waste time?"_ Well, no. I'd prefer not to have to wait 5 seconds for every unit test to complete if I could instead have the script _think_ that 5 seconds have passed and carry on from that point.